# Generate report from sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, reports

I need to generate a report from sharepoint 2010 list using any good and easy method.
Any suggestions along with the procedure are welcome.

Answer (score 11):

One of the great things about SharePoint is the ease with which you can create a list, and immediately have an online form people can use to enter data. Of course, once you have data in your SharePoint list, you’re inevitably going to want to implement some type of reporting against it. What’s the point of collecting all of this data if we can’t gain insight from it anyway?

For some scenarios, reporting against your SharePoint list might be as simple as creating one or more custom views for the list that group or filter the data in a meaningful way. More often than not, however, I see users with needs that require functionality above and beyond what a simple list view can provide. They might need charts, cascading parameters/filters, sorting capabilities, and all the other common functionality we’ve grown accustomed with from modern reporting. Let’s take a look at a few options that deliver all the bells and whistles most users are looking for.

**Reporting services:** Reporting services allow us to connect directly to a SharePoint list as a data source. Once a SharePoint list data source has been created, you can then create data sets that query the list using the Query Builder tool inside the reporting services development environment.

Using reporting services in this manner allows you to query the data directly for real-time reporting against your list, but it does come with a few drawbacks. The language used to query SharePoint lists (CAML) isn’t as robust as other query languages you may be familiar with (T-SQL/MDX/DAX). For example, creating a distinct list of values from a list column (something commonly needed for report parameter dropdowns) takes some additional effort and a little scripting to achieve.

**PowerPivot:** PowerPivot can connect to SharePoint lists using OData feeds. Setting up this connection is as easy as locating the correct URL for the endpoint and walking through a simple connection wizard in your PowerPivot window.

Using this method, PowerPivot will download and store all of data currently in your SharePoint list, so your PowerPivot report will only be as current as the last time the workbook was refreshed. Having your SharePoint list data stored in the PowerPivot workbook does have the added advantage of being able to leverage the full capabilities of PowerPivot while reporting against your SharePoint lists, such as relating your list data to other sources, and in creating additional calculations using the DAX language.

[Source](http://www.sptechweb.com/link/64091)

**Out-of-box Solutions**

SharePoint has some reporting options built in:

■Create your own views from the settings page

■Pros: can be for all users or just for you, allows filtering (including the Me filter, which displays just your items)

■Cons: can’t join two lists, have to have correct permissions

**■How-to links:**

■http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-mod...

■http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinaayoub/archive/2010/04/22/sharepoint-2010-how-to-create-a-view.aspx

**■Create views using SharePoint Designer**

■Pros: variety of layout options, ability to join two lists

■Cons: SharePoint Designer learning curve, easy to break things

■How-to links:

■https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/How-to-Link-Two-Lists-and-Create-a-Combined-View-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

■http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-view-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010379079.aspx

**More Flexible**

Sometimes you need to be able to visualize the data in ways that aren’t possible in a list view. More flexible options include

**■Excel workbook linked to list(s)**

Pros: familiar interface, powerful calculation and analysis engines

■Pros: new features like PowerPivot and PowerView allow for data modelling and aesthetically pleasing reporting

■Pros: PowerPivot Gallery in SharePoint (on-prem only at this time) allow you to publish and share easily

**■How-to links:**

■http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/power-view-explore-visualize-and-present-your-data-HA102835634.aspx

■http://www.powerpivotpro.com/what-is-powerpivot/

■http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xhwOEGjhxw

**■Access database linked to list(s)**

■Pros: Access can be used to report on complex data spanning two or more lists

■Pros: easy to read & write, familiar interface for some users

■How-to links:

■http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBA-Sz72Spw

■http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/export-or-link-a-datasheet-view-to-access-HA001160860.aspx

**Most Scalable**

Enterprise reporting solutions can help you keep up on your data even as it grows.

**■SQL Server Reporting Services**

■Pros: powerful reporting tool, can use lookup functions (2008 R2 or later) or sub-reports to join list data

■Pros: Report Builder integrated with SharePoint

■Pros: can be scheduled or subscribed to

■Cons: requires server install of product

■How-to links:

■http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/07/create-a-sharepoint-ssrs-report-library/

■http://aproblemshared.fusionmanageit.co.uk/2012/08/aggregated-lookups-in-ssrs.html

■http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210649(v=sql.105).aspx

**■PerformancePoint**

■Pros: reusable KPIs, integration with other Microsoft products (including SSRS reports!)

■Pros: can consume data from an Excel PowerPivot model

■Cons: requires SharePoint Enterprise or E3/E4 for Office 365

■Cons: some features only available for data cubes

■How-to links:

■http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb660518.aspx

■http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VOG4fXr3v4

■http://blog.technock.net/2013/03/sharepoint-2010-performance-point-score.html

■http://gnetgroup.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/building-a-performancepoint-dashboard-without-a-cube/

■http://blog.netnerds.net/2012/03/sharepoint-2010-creating-dashboards-and-charts-for-sharepoint-lists-using-performancepoint-and-excel-services/

[Source](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/reporting-options-for-sharepoint-lists)

And also have a look at the below links

[SharePoint 2010 Performance Point Service Configuration and Utilization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386150/SharePoint-2010-Performance-Point-Service-Configur)

[Getting a SharePoint List Data Source to work with Reporting Services Native Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2013/06/11/getting-a-sharepoint-list-data-source-to-work-with-reporting-services-native-mode.aspx)

Comment: Do any of these solutions allow for scheduled reports? I have requirement where a list report needs to be sent to a group of users at the end of the month but I can't deploy a timer-job or have access to the server in any way

Comment: So, let me ask you a question... how do you create an RS report off of a SharePoint list?